# why use pointers

Tags: pointers, programming-languages

I'm learning C++ on my own. I'm an EE and learned it about 20 years ago, but in the progress of my career I stopped programming and didn't take it up again until recently. I should add that I never took any classes in programming.
 I have a theoretical question about pointers. In reading the books about pointers it seems they have an important role in C++. My problem is that I can't see what that is. I see that pointers have a role in arrays, but I can't see their role in anything else.
  I can see what they do, but I don't see why use pointers in the situations I see them in. Either references or straight variables would work just as well. I have a feeling the answer lies in the area of memory ( it's optimal use), but I just don't know.
  Any answers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What about arrays of arrays ? And linked lists ? And trees ? And graphs ? And dynamic memory allocation ? Also at runtime you need to remember what was the caller functions, this has to be based on pointers.

Comment: Thanks @user1952009.  Actually it's funny, but that is exactly what I need.  Let me ask you a question; is that all you use pointers for? Or is there something else that you use pointers for all the time. I'm hoping thats it.

Comment: What you need to understand is that the computer use pointers for things as simple as `int a = 0; a = 1;` or `new string("abcd");` or `callThisFunction();`. Whenerver you are modifying/writing a value in memory, you are writing at some address, given by a pointer. Pointers are explicit in C/C++/Pascal/Fortran. They are just hidden in other languages, but they are still there,

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/):

> "[T]here may be cases where the memory needs of a program can only be
>   determined during runtime. For example, when the memory needed depends
>   on user input. On these cases, programs need to dynamically allocate
>   memory, for which the C++ language integrates the operators `new` and
>   `delete`."

If you could determine all your memory needs prior to run time and did not need to make use of any abstract data type like a linked list, then yes, it would be difficult to see their use. However, what if you want to store values in an array, but you don't yet know how big that array will need to be?

Another value of pointers arises when you consider passing values from function to function. You may find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in) of value regarding the differences between pointers and references in C++ and how/why to use each.

We have been having several pedagogical conversations focused on pointers on the [CSEducators.SE site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators). I'd encourage you to read those as well:

[Simple Pointer Examples in C](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/299/simple-pointer-examples-in-c)

[Lesson Idea: Arrays, Pointers, and Syntactic Sugar](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/211/lesson-idea-arrays-pointers-and-syntactic-sugar)

Comment: Your example about passing by reference doesn't answer why you'd use pointers to pass by reference instead of C++ references. (And I would argue that generally you shouldn't pass by pointer if you can help it!)

Comment: Good point - thank you for bringing that up. I'll edit appropriately.

Comment: Peter, thanks. I thought the answer was in the area of memory use. I'll definitly check out those other conversations.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers come from **C**, which had no concept of *reference*, and which **C++** inherited from.

Everything that can be done with a *reference* in **C++** is done with a pointer in **C**.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. What about, say, linked structures with dynamically changing links?

Answer (score 0):

I find this question really great because it is pure.

A programming language is considered "safe" when the programs written in it can only call functions and access data that the program can name.

Now, the concept of pointer was invented to break this sandbox of safety and provide developer with freedom to think and act outside of the box.

Think of pointers as poor man's tool to achieve something not provided by the programming language itself.

It is misleading to think you could achieve higher performance if programmed some algorithm using pointers. Optimization is privilege of the compiler and hardware, not human.